# how to fetch array inside object in react native

Tags: react-native

```
Object {
  "errorMessage": "",
  "item": Array [
    Object {
      "created_at": "1572602716",
      "description": "Dbjd",
      "id": "1",
      "title": "Hsh",
      "updated_at": "1572602716",
      "user_id": "27",
    },
    Object {
      "created_at": "1572603684",
      "description": "Hh",
      "id": "2",
      "title": "Gg",
      "updated_at": "1572603684",
      "user_id": "27",
    },
    Object {
      "created_at": "1572603975",
      "description": "Tr",
      "id": "3",
      "title": "Gg",
      "updated_at": "1572603975",
      "user_id": "27",
    },
    Object {
      "created_at": "1572854783",
      "description": "Ggg",
      "id": "7",
      "title": "Gtt",
      "updated_at": "1572854783",
      "user_id": "27",
    },
  ],
```

Comment: `Object.item` will give you the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can type the objectName.item , suppose here ,

```
let data = {
  "errorMessage": "",
  "item": Array [
    Object {
      "created_at": "1572602716",
      "description": "Dbjd",
      "id": "1",
      "title": "Hsh",
      "updated_at": "1572602716",
      "user_id": "27",
    },
    Object {
      "created_at": "1572603684",
      "description": "Hh",
      "id": "2",
      "title": "Gg",
      "updated_at": "1572603684",
      "user_id": "27",
    },
    Object {
      "created_at": "1572603975",
      "description": "Tr",
      "id": "3",
      "title": "Gg",
      "updated_at": "1572603975",
      "user_id": "27",
    },
    Object {
      "created_at": "1572854783",
      "description": "Ggg",
      "id": "7",
      "title": "Gtt",
      "updated_at": "1572854783",
      "user_id": "27",
    },
  ],
```

You can access the item array by simply ,

```
data.item
```

Comment: this object come from state so it have no name .kindly help

Comment: it must have a name in state, can you share your code?

Comment: like this.state.data.item to access the array

Comment: export default ArticleScreen = () => {
  const { state, GetArticle } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [data3, setdata] = useState("");
  
   const data=state
  console.log(data);
then output previous object that hve no name